# How to get the string value only in select tag angular?

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/SxdjrBeUF48DrdFQuFHz?p=preview

I have a selected and I want to get the value only.

this is what I currently getting

```
{"_code":"AUD","description":"AUD - Australian Dollar"}
```

what I want to get

```
"AUD"
```

how can I accomplish this, below is my code.

```
<select ng-model="myModel"
    ng-options="o.description for o in currencies track by o._code">
</select>
```

Note: I can't `ng-repeat` my `<option>` tag instead, because I am trying to edit object and I want it to be selected in the select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-options="o._code as o.description for o in currencies"
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/UZy39F4CwX8Ey8WryWVm?p=preview